# WriteableBitmap blending oddly with background grid

Tags: wpf, writeablebitmap

I'm experimenting with drawing to a WriteableBitmap assigned to an Image control within WPF and I am finding that the color values are blending with the background color even when the alpha values are set to 0.

I have the following main window

```
<Window x:Class="WriteableBitmapTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="#999">
        <Image x:Name="testImage"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm populating the image control with the following code - expecting that setting the alpha byte to 0 would produce nothing visible.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const int Size = 300;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.testImage.Source = CreateBitmap();
        }

        private ImageSource CreateBitmap()
        {
            var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
                Size,
                Size,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Pbgra32,
                null);

            bitmap.Lock();
            FillBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap.Unlock();

            return bitmap;
        }

        private void FillBitmap(WriteableBitmap writableBitmap)
        {
            var stride = writableBitmap.BackBufferStride;
            var bytesPerPixel = writableBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
            var pixelRows = Size;
            var pixels = new byte[pixelRows * stride * bytesPerPixel];

            for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += bytesPerPixel)
            {
                pixels[i + 0] = 0x00;  // B
                pixels[i + 1] = 0x00;  // G
                pixels[i + 2] = 0xff;  // R
                pixels[i + 3] = 0x00;  // A <--- expect the R value to be ignored when rendered.
            }

            var rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, Size, Size);
            writableBitmap.WritePixels(rect, pixels, stride, 0);
        }
    }
```

Instead, I see a red square that appears to have blended with the background color (which I've set to gray).

[image: light red square over grey background]

I'm wondering if there's any trick to control this blending behaviour? or am I expected to factor in the background color if I'm writing straight to the pixel data like this.

Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PixelFormats.Bgra32` instead of `PixelFormats.Pbgra32`, which would require a pre-multiplied `R` value of `0`.

From the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pixelformats.pbgra32?view=windowsdesktop-7.0):

> Gets the Pbgra32 pixel format. Pbgra32 is a sRGB format with 32 bits per pixel (BPP). Each channel (blue, green, red, and alpha) is allocated 8 bits per pixel (BPP). **Each color channel is pre-multiplied by the alpha value**.

Besides that, your buffer is too large. `bitmap.PixelHeight * stride` is a sufficient size, i.e. the number of rows multiplied by the number of bytes per row.

`bitmap.Lock()` and `bitmap.Unlock()` are also not required for `WritePixels`.

Finally, you should not use `BackBufferStride` when you write a pixel buffer that contains a consecutive sequence of pixel. For performance reasons `BackBufferStride` could have a different value than the actual stride of your source buffer.

```
private ImageSource CreateBitmap()
{
    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
        300,
        300,
        96,
        96,
        PixelFormats.Bgra32,
        null);

    FillBitmap(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}

private void FillBitmap(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
{
    var bytesPerPixel = 4; // required for code below
    var stride = bitmap.PixelWidth * bytesPerPixel;
    var pixels = new byte[bitmap.PixelHeight * stride];

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += bytesPerPixel)
    {
        pixels[i + 0] = 0x00; // B
        pixels[i + 1] = 0x00; // G
        pixels[i + 2] = 0xFF; // R
        pixels[i + 3] = 0x00; // A
    }

    var rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight);
    bitmap.WritePixels(rect, pixels, stride, 0);
}
```